# HTML attribute class

Tags: html, angular, angular4-forms

Is there any way to write class for HTML attributes?
I'm having problem with a code

```
(i.e) <input type="text" class="float-label" required/>
```

In the above code my 'float-label' class works fine when the input attribute having the attribute 'required'. Once I remove the required attribute the class behave differently.

**Update:**

When the input field has `required` then the class takes the `class:invalid` state, when removing the `required` attribute then the class takes `class:valid` condition. I don't know why the class takes valid condition when the input have `required` attribute.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Share your full css code may for "required" field has common styles.

Answer (score 0):

If **required** field is not given on any input then there should be other validations checking mechanism applied,if not applied then the angular form considers it as a **valid** even after not witting any thing on the input so **class:valid** gets applied.Please go thorough following references : 
[angular form validations](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation)

[ngform basics](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)

```
check plunker example style.css will give you brief idea for applying classes:
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0HUW5A4KTSUwWzgy7cBV?p=info